# A record of questions answered

Tags: feature-request, deletion

**Question**: Is there a way to keep a record of one's own answers (including stats and votes) to questions that are deleted?

Thanks!

Comment: like this:http://math.stackexchange.com/users/2720/user02138 ?

Comment: @a little don: "to questions that are deleted"

Comment: Is deleted the same as "closed" since closed questions such as "How can I write a paper in algebraic geometry?" for user02138 still show up on our profile pages.

Comment: Nope. I answered a question about proving some identity of nested roots and a trig formula that Chandru1 posted. He deleted it and now my answer is gone.... ;(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like [an isdeleted:1 search operator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41130/can-we-have-an-isdeleted1-search-option-operator)?  Sorry, doesn't look like there will be one.